# Import chart into Blender Graph Editor

Tags: animation, import

I am doing an animation and i would like to import my f-curve from a chart which has f.e. on the x-axis=frame and on the y-axis= scale. I know that there is a Add-On doing that but it is not working in 2.69 neither in 2.7+, which can be found here http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?209181-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-F-Curves-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)
So is there any way i can still import a chart from excel to Blender to give specific animation points?
regards hans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import chart to Graph editor with an add-on you refer to. 
It is fixed now by Chebhou :) You can download script from [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?209181-A-Script-to-Import-a-CSV-File-and-Create-F-Curves-(for-Blender-2-5x-or-later)&p=2857860&viewfull=1#post2857860).
Add-on appears in a Scene properties panel and works as expected in 2.74 (seems to me).

Answer (score 1):

I only see one part of the script that doesn't work, the menu for the data_path.

Find this line in the script -

```
colsubsub.prop_search(config, "data_path", config_top, "data_path_candidates", text="", icon='RNA')
```

and replace it with -

```
colsubsub.prop(config, "data_path")
```

You won't get a menu to select options from but you can manually type in one of the following options that work -

```
location
rotation_euler
rotation_quaternion
scale
```

Note that rotation_euler imports the data as radians not degrees.

Comment: I can't enable add-on with your replaced line 433 from User preferences in version 2.74.

Comment: @vklidu see my reply on the BA thread on how to register